# Bootstrap persisting after being removed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I originally had linked to the Bootstrap CDN in order to use Font Awesome icons but was having issues with class names I wanted to use matching the Bootstrap classes, so I removed the Bootstrap CDN link in my index.html and was planning on just downloading and installing the font-awesome files (without Bootstrap). But the Bootstrap class names are persisting in my browser (Chrome) with absolutely no mention of Bootstrap anywhere in my code. Additionally, this problem does not occur if I open Chrome in an incognito window. I do have disable cache checked in my Chrome dev tools network tab.

Is there something I'm not thinking of that's letting Bootstrap persist in my browser even after removing all references to Bootstrap in my code?

Update: Here's the HTML in question:

`<div className="social-links">
     <a href="" className="footer-link-social"><i className="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
     <a href="" className="footer-link-social"><i className="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
     <a href="" className="footer-link-social"><i className="fa fa-github-square"></i></a>
     <a href="" className="footer-link-social"><i className="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
</div>`

Currently the div with className "social-links" is showing up in Chrome Dev Tools with a laundry list of Bootstrap-default class names (with my .social-links in bold in that list). This class names list is showing up in Chrome Dev Tools between where my main CSS would be and the CSS from using normalize.css. I don't actually have any of my own CSS to show here - I haven't even written any yet. And Bootstrap is not longer anywhere in my code. I'm not importing it, I don't have it installed. And I'm still not having this problem if I open in an incognito window.

I did try the right-click on the refresh button to hard refresh and clear cache but it didn't do anything.

I am using Webpack to bundle, and creating different bundled files (my code, vendor libraries). Is there any way that Webpack could be keeping the Bootstrap stuff in my code even though I removed it and have run my Webpack server and build multiple times since removing Bootstrap?

I have checked my bundled CSS and there is no Bootstrap code in it. At this point the only code inside is from normalize.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. My adblocker was screwing everything up by checking for a huge list of class names and creating a style tag with all of them in order to block anything using those classes.

Comment: Ah! That's a new one on me, but I'm glad you sorted it out. What was the name of the adblocker you're using? It'd be good to include that here just in case anyone else also has this issue.

Comment: Superblock Adblocker. On a side note, it was also screwing with social media icons in email signatures.

Answer (score 0):

With chrome dev tools open, right click on the 'reload' icon in the browser window and you'll see a dropdown that isn't normally available. Click 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'. You can also try hard reloading by pressing 'control+f5' (on PC) or 'option+f5' (on Mac).

[image]

If the problem persists after this step, I might be able to provide addtional information if your post the HTML & CSS of your page, either here or via a [gist](https://gist.github.com/).